# Send a variable to a PHP page and open the page in new tab

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've this code

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    var my_data = 'Test Test Tes';

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "preview.php",
      data: "my_data=" + my_data,
      success: function() {
        window.open('preview.php');
      },
    });
  });
```

Above codes open the `preview.php` but I'm getting this error -

> Notice: Undefined index: my_data in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tb-builder\preview.php on line 3

This is what I've in `preview.php` -

```
<?php
    $data= $_POST['my_data'];
    echo $data;
?>
```

Can anybody help me to solve this please? Thanks

Comment: Send your data as `data: {my_data:my_data},`

Comment: @Saty not working the way you mentioned.

Comment: Where you define `html_template` in `preview.php` file??

Comment: @JamesThorpe passing a string is fine if the string is properly encoded, which it is not.

Comment: actually its `my_data` not `html_template`. edited the question

Comment: Is your error in new window ??

Comment: Comment this line and check `window.open('preview.php');`

Comment: yes. in new window

Comment: Have you tried $_REQUEST?

Comment: Why should be anything in the post in a newly created window from success? First ajax post the data to the preview page, then open a new window. It does not matter, that is the same file, click not triggered on the new window, so why should be there any `$_POST` thing?

Comment: I think the `final Update ` I made is exactly what you wanted rather than a `ajax` request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Main error is , `window.open('preview.php');` loads the page `preview.php` ,
>    
> You are not sending any data with `post/get` request while loading it using 
>   `window.open('preview.php');` and you are expecting value at `$_POST['my_data']`

```
  $(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    var my_data = 'Test Test Tes';

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "preview.php",
      data: "my_data=" + my_data,
    });
  });
```

**preview.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['my_data']){
    $data= $_POST['my_data'];
    header('location:preview.php?my_data=$data');  //reload preview.php with the `my_data`
   }
   if(isset($_GET['my_data'])){
      $data=$_GET['my_data'];    
    echo $data;             //display `my_data` as you requested
   }
?>
```

## Update

> With out using ajax ,to achieve what you required.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    var my_data = 'Test Test Tes';
        window.open('preview.php?my_data='+my_data);
  });
```

**preview.php**

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['my_data'])){
        $data=$_GET['my_data'];    
        echo $data;          
 }
?>
```

---

#### final Update

> Actually you don't need `ajax` at all , because you are going to another page with the data .

**to avoid `get` request**

> Wrap the `button` inside a `form` with hidden `input` having value
>   `my_data` and set `action="preview.php"` **like below**

```
<form action="preview.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="my_data" value="Test Test Tes">
  <button type="submit" id="button">post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your solution working. But worried that users will be seeing the data in address bar which wont look good. So is there any way to avoid it? and is there any character limits of sending data using this method?

Comment: @XahedKamal You need to read the ajax section from the basics I think

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` just create a new `window` object. That window will have no `$_POST` globals. Use `window.open('preview.php?my_data=' + my_data);` and use `$_GET['my_data']` in that PHP.

The post is related to the ajax not for the new window.

**EDIT**

Ok guys, I see here is a little confusion.

> Above codes **open** the preview.php but I'm getting this error -

So what happens?

OP is sending a data called `my_data` to the `preview.php`. This data is travelling through `$_POST` to the `preview.php`. At this point, there is `$_POST['my_data'];`

When it finish with success, the ajax call, then the `window.open` opens a **new window**, what has no `$_POST` data, this is why OP get this error message.

If he want to use the same data what he posted in `my_data` then he need to add it to the URL and use `$_GET`.

I think the misunderstood was what @HoangHieu wrote and me pointed:

> yes. in new window – Xahed Kamal

And if you want to use response, then use

```
success: function(reponse) {
   window.open('preview.php?my_data=' + response);
},
```

and then use `$_GET['my_data']` in **new** window.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (isset($_POST['my_data']))    
{    
    $data= $_POST['my_data'];
    echo $data; 
}
```

Comment: same answer but few seconds late :)

Comment: that doesn't fix anything you are just getting rid of the error message

Comment: Why you make downvot? You can see we have just 8 second difference , no one can copy and pest the code within 8 seconds...

Comment: Also an `else` would be great in that case.

Comment: @HarshSanghani removed , sorry .

Answer (score 0):

Please change your preview.php code with the following :-

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['my_data']))
    {
       $data= $_POST['my_data'];
       echo $data;
    }
?>
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It was completed question in

**Is your error in new window ?? – HoangHieu 1 min ago**

**yes. in new window – Xahed Kamal**

First Ajax post it completed when **success:** function called... In new window you doesn't have any post data, I don't know any solution post data by javascript to new window.. only one you can send data by **GET** request ..

Comment: This is what I've sad exactly, and guess what, a downvote.

Comment: I'm not very good on Ajax and PHP. So i'm not sure how to do it. So let me explain what i'm trying to get. I want to pass some data via ajax to another php page and echo those data there. So, if you could show me a sample codes would be better from me to understand

Comment: why do you want to send the date with Ajax if you are trying to display it in a new page. Won't it be easier just to open the page in a new window with the data passed as `GET` parameters?

Comment: i've a page where i need to pass some html elements (depending on user's selection) and then show it on new window like a preview.

Comment: Yes @VelimirTchatchevsky I make me can't understand

Comment: Why you don't save it by Session or Cookies, GET request it make bester than all it for show data to open new page by javascript.. Or you can POST data by submit form.

Answer (score -1):

Your construct:

```
data: "my_data=" + my_data,
```

Is wrong. It should be:

```
data: {my_data: $my_data},
```

And I changed your JS variabale to `$my_data`, so it's less confusing.