# call a new PHP page and pass a long text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP page(main) and would like to call another PHP page(printpage) on mouse click.  I need to pass a large text.

I do not want to pass it as a url parameter as it will be too big.
I guess I want to pass it as an ajax but I want to open the printpage so I can print it in the browser.

```
I started with this but the paramater will be too big
    $('#MyModal .print').click(function() {
        var   run = "../js/print.php?ref="+ref;
        win = window.open(run, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    });
```

I am familar with the ajax statement but have not used to open a new page.

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051486/send-a-variable-to-a-php-page-and-open-the-page-in-new-tab see if it helps.  The data is passed as post data.

Comment: @NigelRen I tried to follow that post but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an invisible form with a `target="_blank"` and `method="post"` and submit it, thereby sending a POST request in a new window:

```html
<form name="printForm" style="display: none;" action="../js/print.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="ref">
</form>
```

```js
$('#MyModal .print').click(function() {
  document.forms.printForm.ref.value = ref
  document.forms.printForm.submit()
})
```

Then you get the `ref` value in PHP as `$_POST['ref']`

Comment: Really simple solution which did the trick.. thanks!